Azure SQL Server Metrics : is 100% CPU percentage is a blocker for all DB operations?
This is with Azure Sql managed Instance, We have observed a case in our database where the CPU percentage is 100% for quite some time but my application are still able to hit & operate over DB, is 100% CPU usage isn't a blocker for DB operations?
I see 2 CPU metrics

CPU Percentage(MAX)
SQL instance CPU percentage(MAX) what is the difference between them? In my case CPU percentage is 100% but SQL Instance CPU percentage is 50% only


please share me insights on this metrics and how to translate this.

I'll assume your question pertains to full fledged SQL server (not AZ SQL database, not managed instance ...). Given the lack of details in your question, I can only give you broader answer.
In general, yes, your SQL server will be able to service clients even under 100% load.
Troubleshooting SQL server's performance from task manager or performance monitor is a tedious task.
You need to ask your SQL server several things:

How fast it is going
How hard it is working
How much weight it is carrying

For initial diagnosis of a SQL box, I recommend First Responder Kit. It's a set of SQL scripts you download and run, which results in stored procedures being created in database of your choice (I recommend master database). Once you "install" the firstresponderkit scripts, to answer three above stated questions, you'll run:
EXEC sp_blitzfirst @seconds = 30, @expertmode = 1;

This T-SQL query does several things, mainly:

"samples" SQL server performance counters at the beginning of execution
"samples" perf counters after 30 seconds
calculates deltas (what happened in these 30 seconds) and gives you answer to three above stated questions, you should see at least:

Amount of batch requests per second (how fast are we going)
Database sizes in total (how much weight are we carrying)
Wait statistics**



**One of the result sets in the returned data from sp_blitzfirst will be WAIT STATS. The thread time and the wait type will give you answer regarding how much your CPU is busy from SQL server's standpoint. If you have e.g. 30 seconds sample, 8 cores box and 250 seconds of thread time, that means (in theory) that your CPU could process 240 seconds of thread time (8x30 = 240) but has work for 10 seconds more (250 - 240 = 10) - i.e. your CPU could be bottleneck. For introduction to wait types, see: Paul Randal's explanation.

thanks @sranda for the details
i  was refering to Azure Sqlserver instance can you please add details inline with the same.

OK, on ManagedInstance, the abovementioned steps will work similarly with some nuances - please try proceeding in respect to what's written above. Potential confusion will be clarified later on.

@Manoj Please note that Azure SQL Server isn't a thing. Either you're using a SQL Server instance in a VM in an Azure hosted cloud, or you're using one of the derivative cloud database products such as Azure SQL Managed Instance or Azure SQL Database, etc.

@J.D. I took my bet and thought he's using managed instance. There I'd at least start with FirstResponderKit too.

Thanks @J.D& @sranda
want to bring my base questions "when my CPU percentage is 100% my database was served without any downtime how is this possible ? " ideally ti should be a downtime for consumers.
is this the case the CPU percentage is 100% but not sqlserver CPU percentage ?
